# How to prevent users from editing or deleting other user posts ? Django

Tags: python, django

Each user has his own posts and he can edit them, but now he can edit other users posts 
here is my edit_post

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
   if request.method == "POST":
      form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
      if form.is_valid():
         post = form.save(commit=False)
         post.user = request.user
         post.published_date = timezone.now()
         post.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
   else:
         form = PostForm(instance=post)
return render(request, 'blog/post_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the current user is the original author of the post and take appropriate action if not:

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
   if post.user != request.user:
      raise Http404  # or similar
   # ...
```

Ideally, you would also check that in the template and show the form to the author and not to anybody else.

Comment: yesssssssss it works :D So please tell me how to do that ( the check thing )